# How do i compensate the accelerometer by 90 degrees corona using Lua

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I am making my game in landscapeRight mode, but i cant get the accelerometer calibrated as landscape because by default in corona the accelerometer is always configured in portrait

As the corona guide says

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/accelerometer/xGravity.html

"So, if your application is running in landscape mode, you'll need to compensate by 90 degrees."

but how do i compensate by 90 degrees the accelerometer ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the phone is rotated from portrait to landscape right (home button on right hand side) the x and y axes swap positions. The x axis of portrait becomes the y axis of landscape right and the y axis becomes the x axis of landscape right except that the direction (+/-) is also reversed.

[image: Coordinate System in Portrait mode]

```
function portraitToLandscapeRight(x, y, z)
   return -y, x, z
end

function portraitToLandscapeLeft(x, y, z)
   return y, -x, z
end
```

Comment: Hooo i never thought about that Thanks !!